# c# pdf itextsharp text scattered and repeated while Extracting

Tags: c#, pdf

Using itextsharp I need to extract text from pdf in a c# application. When I am trying to extract some of the pdf files, some words gets scattered and repeated(for eg. stack overflow - s st ta ac ck k o ov ve er rf fl lo ow w). Can someone suggest how to make this perfect or suggest me to correct this. I have attached a sample image for the above case.
[image]

Comment: dont disclose information about any individual on stackoverflow please!

Answer (score 2):

Can I take a guess that the text causing this is in **bold** in the PDF file? A not uncommon way to make text look bold in PostScript and PDF (a very bad way but well...) is to render the same characters twice, with a very slight translation (shift) of the position of the text.

If that is indeed what is causing this, your only way around it is probably to calculate the position of each character and discard those characters that are equal and very close together.

Comment: A poor man's bold would be my guess, too. @ShankarManickavasagam please supply a sample PDF to inspect. If this is the case, the strategy can be appropriately extended to recognize some common patterns of it